# PermissionError: [WinError 32] when updating existing fits file

Tags: python-3.x, fits, windows-11

I'm working on win11 with python 3.9.7 and I'm trying to open a fits datacube that has different layers and append a new one and then save it, but when I do that, I get the following error: **"PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"**

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
from astropy.io import fits
Datacube=fits.open(path2tile,memmap=False,mode='update')
Datacube.append(fits.ImageHDU(data=data,name='new layer'))
print(Datacube.info())
Datacube.writeto(path2tile,overwrite=True)
```

where path2tile is some path to the datacube I want to open and data is the new data I want to append to the existing datacube. I also tested different mode options but nothing works so far.

This is the output of the print statement:

```
No.    Name      Ver    Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
  0  PRIMARY       1 PrimaryHDU       4   ()      
  1  SCI           1 ImageHDU         8   (31, 31)   float64   
  2  ERR           1 ImageHDU         8   (31, 31)   float64   
  3  DQ            1 ImageHDU         8   (31, 31)   float64   
  4  CRCELANSCI    1 ImageHDU         8   (31, 31)   float32   
  5  NEW LAYER     1 ImageHDU         8   (31, 31)   float32
```

So the new data is actually appended to the datacube, but for some reason, it can not be saved. The error is happening at the Datacube.writeto(path2tile,overwrite=True) line when it try to save the file.
Anyone has any idea why this is happening and how can I fix it/bypass it?

Comment: "Anyone has any idea why this is happening" Well, the error message says that it is "because it is being used by another process". Why does this not answer the question adequately? (Hint: `fits.open` *opens a file*, right? `Datacube.writeto` will also try to open that file, right? Maybe there should be some kind of code to close it in between? Did you try *reading the documentation* for `fits.open`?)

Comment: Yes I read the documentation and also other answers here on stackoverflow but I couldn't find anything useful. I have no other programs or call that are keeping the file open (at the best of my knowledge of course). The only thing calling the file is the opening statement. Bit that I need I guess. I don't think I can close it before saving it right?

Comment: Yes, the error detection can't actually tell that it's the *same* process trying to open the file twice, so that probably is the point of confusion. "I don't think I can close it before saving it right?" Why not? You finished doing the reading at that point, yes? When you call `fits.open`, you get a particular sort of object, right? How about the documentation *for that class*? Do you see anything about closing the file?

Comment: Even if I add '''Datacube.close()''' before the '''Datacube.writeto(path2tile,overwrite=True) ''' I still get an error: '''ValueError: I/O operation on closed file''' that, of course, I'm trying to write on the closed Datacube. Can you please provide a straight answer with a solution and possibly an explanation to why your approach is working?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for an answer to this problem, this is the solution I found:

```
 from astropy.io import fits
 Datacube=fits.open(path2tile,memmap=False,mode='update')
 Datacube.append(fits.ImageHDU(data=data,name='new layer'))
 print(Datacube.info())
 Datacube.flush()
```

With the 'update' mode I just swapped the witeto() with flush() and it's working now. No more **"PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"**

Comment: Instead of manually calling flush you should use the `with` statement which will write any changes and close the file when leaving the context in which the file is opened.